# Access to Azure Cosmos DB from on-premises

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am facing below issue when trying to access Azure Cosmos DB when running an on-prem Springboot application.

```
azure.cosmos.directTcp.defaultOptions
2022-11-04 12:23:16.409  INFO 28700 --- [           main] Endpoint$RntbdEndpointMonitoringProvider : Starting RntbdClientChannelPoolMonitoringProvider ...
2022-11-04 12:23:16.445  INFO 28700 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.a.c.i.GlobalEndpointManager            : Unable to get azure vm metadata
2022-11-04 12:23:19.687  WARN 28700 --- [s-rntbd-nio-2-1] c.a.c.i.d.rntbd.RntbdClientChannelPool   : channel acquisition failed due to

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: cdb-ms-prod-northeurope1-fd58.documents.azure.com/13.69.226.37:11337
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-11-04 12:23:19.687  WARN 28700 --- [s-rntbd-nio-2-3] c.a.c.i.d.rntbd.RntbdClientChannelPool   : channel acquisition failed due to

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: cdb-ms-prod-northeurope1-fd58.documents.azure.com/13.69.226.37:11022
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-11-04 12:23:21.906  WARN 28700 --- [s-rntbd-nio-2-7] c.a.c.i.d.rntbd.RntbdClientChannelPool   : channel acquisition failed due to

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: cdb-ms-prod-northeurope1-fd58.documents.azure.com/13.69.226.37:11335
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-11-04 12:23:24.157  WARN 28700 --- [s-rntbd-nio-2-1] c.a.c.i.d.rntbd.RntbdClientChannelPool   : channel acquisition failed due to

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: cdb-ms-prod-northeurope1-fd58.documents.azure.com/13.69.226.37:11337
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-11-04 12:23:24.157  WARN 28700 --- [s-rntbd-nio-2-7] c.a.c.i.d.rntbd.RntbdClientChannelPool   : channel acquisition failed due to

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: cdb-ms-prod-northeurope1-fd58.documents.azure.com/13.69.226.37:11335
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-11-04 12:23:26.360  WARN 28700 --- [s-rntbd-nio-2-3] c.a.c.i.d.rntbd.RntbdClientChannelPool   : channel acquisition failed due to

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: cdb-ms-prod-northeurope1-fd58.documents.azure.com/13.69.226.37:11022
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-11-04 12:23:26.369  WARN 28700 --- [-rntbd-nio-2-15] c.a.c.i.directconnectivity.QuorumReader  : QuorumNotSelected: Quorum could not be selected with read quorum of 2
2022-11-04 12:23:28.559  WARN 28700 --- [-rntbd-nio-2-16] c.a.c.i.d.rntbd.RntbdClientChannelPool   : channel acquisition failed due to

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: cdb-ms-prod-northeurope1-fd58.documents.azure.com/13.69.226.37:11051
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-11-04 12:23:30.822  WARN 28700 --- [-rntbd-nio-2-16] c.a.c.i.d.rntbd.RntbdClientChannelPool   : channel acquisition failed due to

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: cdb-ms-prod-northeurope1-fd58.documents.azure.com/13.69.226.37:11051
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I am running this project from Idea Intellij, i have set up manual proxy for my organization

pom dependency being used to access cosmos :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-cosmos</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: have you allowed the ip in the network settings?

Comment: yes i have added them

Comment: Are the ports open for TCP operations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-connection-modes#service-port-ranges

Comment: Probably a good idea to edit your question and show more details, such as code you're running. Currently you only included some error output with no other context.